# Qualify bean based on the bean name in spring

Tags: spring

From title this seems straightforward we use @qualify with @autowired in our application to inject bean in our code.

I have two classes having @component annotation and they both implement same class.

```
@Component
class A extends B{  
}

@Component
class C extends B{  
}
```

When application starts as both beans of same type while starting application, application fails with the below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'JI' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: a,b
```

Issue is as am not injecting these beans the spring is injecting I want to tell spring inject these beans by bean name and not type runtime.

Application starts well when the first request comes this fails with the error given.

I tried this below -

```
@Component
@Qualifier("a")
class A extends B{  
}

@Component
@Qualifier("c")
class C extends B{  
}
```

But still get the same error.

Any suggestions as how do I make this work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the name of bean while injecting it.

```
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("c") // or "a"
   private TargetClass targetClass;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is not am expecting. As I told you I am not autowiring them in my class. I am just creating components and they are of the same type.

Comment: Did you try cleaning and again building the project again?

Comment: `com.hsbcib.securities.ecomlib.job.JobImplementation` where you are using them? post the code

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'JI' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: a,b

Comment: This comes from the library I am using as maven dependency I can not edit that code.

Comment: My requirement is spring should pick based on the bean name not type. I am not injecting these beans some outer code is using my code. Hope this will be more clearer.

Comment: This is what I am saying. post the code where this code is being used.